# Resize Shape between Subtitle and Footer in Powerpoint Slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, shapes

Is there a way to resize shapes(pictures,tables,charts) pasted from an Excel Worksheet to Powerpoint slides, so that each shape is resized relative to it's original dimensions (LockAspectRatio=True) and placed exactly between a Slide's SubTitle and Footer and centered horizontally?

The Shapes may be of varying sizes i.e. sometimes very small or sometimes greater than the dimensions of the Slide. Therefore the criteria is to resize them (without distorting) to fit nicely between the Subtitle and footer and horizontally center-aligned.

Is this possible using Excel VBA?

**Edit: Below logic is not working correctly.**

```
Sub ResizeShapesInSlide()

Dim L#, T#, W#, H#, SlideCnt%, i%
Dim sHeight#, sWidth#
Dim oSlide As Slide, oShp As Shape

SlideCnt = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

For i = 1 To SlideCnt
    Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
    With oSlide
        .Select

        ' get Slide height & width
        sHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight
        sWidth = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth

        Set oShp = .Shapes("Picture 1")
        With oShp
            .Select
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

            ' resize if image larger than Slide dimensions
            If .Width >= sWidth Then .Width = sWidth - oSlide.Shapes("SubTitle").Left
            If .Height >= sHeight Then .Height = sHeight - oSlide.Shapes("Footer").Top

'            L = .Left: T = .Top: W = .Width: H = .Height

            ' Set shape Top to SubTitle Top + Height
            .Top = (oSlide.Shapes("SubTitle").Top + oSlide.Shapes("SubTitle").Height) + 5

            ' Initially set Shape to SubTitle Left
            .Left = oSlide.Shapes("SubTitle").Left

             ' now adjust Shape height till Footer Top
            .Height = .Height - (sHeight - oSlide.Shapes("Footer").Top - 5)

            ' finally center shape horizontally
            .Left = (sWidth - .Width) / 2
        End With
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this sounds very doable.

Comment: @BigBen, i have updated my post with the code i was using. It does not seem to resize  every shape between the subtitle and footer and center horizontally.

Comment: What exactly does it do incorrectly? And does it do it for all shapes or just certain shapes? If certain shapes, what's the shape type?  Incidentally, neither of the two Select statements in your code is necessary. I'd comment them out (and enjoy watching your code run faster)